# :: without a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

Consider the following line of code:

```
::CGContextRef cgContext = cocoa::createCgBitmapContext( surface );
```

How come there's **no namespace specified before ::** ?
Does that mean it's using the same namespace as the class you're in?

Answer (score 23):

`::` in `::CGContextRef` means global namespace, which means `CGContextRef` is defined in the global namespace.

```
int x = 10; 
namespace test
{
    int x = 100;
    void f() 
    {
         std::cout << x << std::endl;  //prints 100
         std::cout << ::x << std::endl; //prints 10
    }     
}
```

See complete demo here : http://www.ideone.com/LM8uo

Answer (score 8):

The :: refers to the global namespace.

Answer (score 5):

`::` without any namespace name before it means it refers ***Global Namespace***.

```
::CGContextRef cgContext = cocoa::createCgBitmapContext( surface );
```

means refer to `CGContextRef` in the Global Namespace.