# What is the difference between "namespace::fn" and "::fn" without the namespace?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ namespace question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966647/c-namespace-question)

I have seen a couple of examples where there isnt a namespace. What is the advantage of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `::fn` refers to something in the global namespace (it is an absolute path). Note you can import stuff into the global namespace using the `using <obj>;` or `using namespace <name>`;

The `namespace::fn` refers to something in a namespace relative to the current namespace (it is a relativepath).

```
namespace X
{
     namespace Y
     {
           int Z()
           {
               N::fn();
               // Compiler looks for
               //      ::X::Y::N::fn()
               //      ::X::N::fn()
               //      ::N::fn()
               //
               // The search is done in that order the first found
               // is used. Note this is done at compile time only.


               ::fn(); // Absolute path. No search done.
                       // looks for `fn()` in the global namespace

               fn();   // Relative path no namespace
                       // Searchs for ::X::Y::fn()
                       //             ::X::fn()
                       //             ::fn()



               ::X::fn(); // Absolute path no search done.
                          // looks for `fn()` in the namespace X which must be
                          // in the global namespace.
           }
     }          
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

`::fn` refers to something called `fn` in the *global* namespace.

Comment: What is the advantage of having things in the global namespace?

Comment: @kunj2aan your root namespace _must_ be in the global namespace, for one. Other times there will be multiple paths to the same name with normal name resolution, or one name hides the other, and you want to specify one.

Comment: @kunj2aan: None. It is just an absolute path. You could have done `::X::Y::Z::fn()`. The leading `::` just means its absolute and start from the global (root) namespace.

Answer (score 2):

you want to use `::fn` when you have two variables with this name, one declared inside a function and another at the global scope. So if you want to deal with global fn inside that function (where local fn is declared) you need to call it `::fn` in order to distinguish between them

```
int fn = 5;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
      int fn = 10;
      std::cout << "local fn is " << fn << " global fn is " << ::fn;  
      return 0;

}
```