# Questions regarding C++ string

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

```
phrase.erase(remove_if (phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), ::isdigit), phrase.end());
```

In the above code, why do I have to use `::` even though I used `using namespace std`?

```
#include "Palindrome.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

Palindrome::Palindrome (string Phrase){
    phrase=Phrase;
}

void Palindrome::removeNonLetters()
{
    phrase.erase(remove_if (phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), ::isdigit), phrase.end());

    phrase.erase(remove_if (phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), ::ispunct), phrase.end());

    phrase.erase(remove_if (phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), ::isspace), phrase.end());
}

void Palindrome::lowerCase()
{
    for (int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++)
    {
        phrase[i] = tolower(phrase[i]); 
    }
}

bool Palindrome::isPalindrome()
{
    int length=phrase.length(); 
    int a=0;    
    for (int i=0;i<length/2;i++)
    { 
        if(phrase[i] != phrase[length-a-1])
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
        a++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above code is to check if the string is a Palindrome. I don't understand why I need to use the first part which is

```
Palindrome::Palindrome (string Phrase){
    phrase=Phrase;
}
```

I will always get "yes" if I deleted the above part.

The test code in main is

```
if(test.Palindrome::isPalindrome() == 1){
    cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
}
else {
    cout<<"No"<<endl;
}
```

One more question. I try to change the lowercase of above code, I got error. Do anyone know what happen with it? The new code was from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/conversion-whole-string-uppercase-lowercase-using-stl-c/

Before

```
 void Palindrome::lowerCase()
{
    for (int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++)
    {
        phrase[i] = tolower(phrase[i]); 
    }
}
```

After

```
void Palindrome::lowerCase(){

transform(phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), phrase.begin, ::tolower);
```

}

Can anyone explain it to me? Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:: without a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966647/without-a-namespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple `isdigit`, `ispunct`, and `isspace` functions - ones in the global namespace in the `<ctype.h>` header, and several in the `std` namespace in the `<cctype>` and `<clocale>` headers.  Prefixing them with `::` says you want to use the ones from the global namespace.

You need to use `<string>` instead of `<string.h>` in order to use the `std::string` class.

Assuming `test` is a `Palindrome` object, then `test.Palindrome::isPalindrome()` should be just `test.isPalindrome()`.

If you omit the `Palindrome` constructor, then the `phrase` member remains blank, and your `isPalindrome()` implementation returns `true` for a blank `phrase` (`length` is 0) because there is nothing for the `for` loop to check.  Which is technically correct - a blank string is a palindrome.

Answer (score -1):

The `::` indicates that you're using `isdigit` and the others from the global namespace. The `isdigit` is a part of other header files, such as `<ctype.h>`.